Custom endpoint in REST API - Wordpress
I have a WordPress website and I want to add a custom endpoint that sends the metadata of the users.
Important:
The already API works only by calling it like this "domain-name.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/".
I know that for the API to work properly the standard solution for a custom endpoint is to change the permalink settings from plain to post.
Is there any solution without changing that setting?
The standard pre-built endpoints work fine when I call them like in the above example.
For example this code only works for the wordpress websites with the permalink settings as post. Calling the api like this (domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/custom-ep. If I place the same code in the other website with permalink setting and call it as mentioned above ("domain-name.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/"), I will get error 404.

code:
function create_custom_endpoint()
{
    register_rest_route(
        'wp/v2', // Namespace
        '/custom-ep', // Route
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET', // HTTP method
            'callback' => 'get_response', // Callback function
        )
    );
}

function get_response()
{
    // This is your custom response data
    return 'This is your data!';
}

// Hook the custom endpoint registration to rest_api_init
add_action('rest_api_init', 'create_custom_endpoint');


why do you want to set pretty url when everything works without ?

@mmm I want my custom endpoint like this "domain-name.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/custom-endpoint/" to work.

why this custom endpoint doesn't work ? edit your question to show the debug you made. why do you speak about permalink settings in your question ?

@mmm this is what I am trying to figure out. I've updated the question.

this is strange, I tried your code and it works for me on url .../wp-json/wp/v2/custom-ep and .../?rest_route=/wp/v2/custom-ep. look in .htaccess if there is something weird.

I was adding the script/snippet in the wrong functions.php file (wrong theme).
I added the code in the correct functions.php and it worked.
